# Android translationY on custom layout

Tags: android, animation, layout, translation

I have a custom layout in my application. I want the layout to shift up when the keyboard pops up. 
I do this by translating my layout along the Y axis using the ObjectAnimator. The problem is that my layout stretches at the bottom. .i.e. **I want to see a black bar underneath my layout, however the layout is simply stretching at the bottom**. 
Any ideas on how I can stop the stretching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...the animation stuffs up if the following item is added to the activity style:

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you try out adding the `<activity android:name=".TodoEdit"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">` in your manifest file, besides managing on your own.

Comment: I have to manage it on my own because the EditText box is above a list view that must be visible at all times. The EditText box is a search box and the results are displayed in the list view. Therefore I need to manually shift my layout so that the keyboard appears below the list view and not the EditText box.